# Как пользоваться => dart

Tags: dart

Столкнулся => с этой фигней в документации, однако не понял как с ней работать что-то пробовал не получилось можете помочь на вот этом примере: void summ (a, b) => return a + b;
Может ссылка есть только я не нашел, кроме документации dart, однако там я не понял.

Comment: Где вы нашли такой пример?

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions

Comment: Вот там в разделе Functions

Comment: Вам будет полезен [этот](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/from-java-to-dart/) учебник ( к сожалению, только на английском).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае речь идет о краткой записи функции, которая "на ходу" возвращает результат:

```dart
int sum1 (int a, int b) => a + b;

int sum2 (int a, int b) { return a + b;}

void main() {
  print(sum1(1,2)); 
  print(sum2(3,4)); 
}
```

Comment: АААа. понял. Спасибо